# Regular expression in expect with tcl

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I need to match the expect for the following output

```
1/ 5  SOMETEXT      Active
```

I am using the following code

```
expect -re "1\/\s+(\d)\s+SOMETEXT\s+Active"
send "\r"
puts $expect_out(0,string)
```

Here, I am matching the digit '5' from the input text.

But, with this code, expect is not able to find the result from the input.

Comment: Have you tried enabling debugging with `exp_internal 1`? That is usually enough to get to the bottom of these kind of problems... it will tell you exactly what is matching and what is not, and you can get info from there so as to adjust your RE.

Comment: what version of Tcl does your expect extend? `puts [info patchlevel]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `expect_out(1,string)` -- that is the 1st captured group
`expect_out(0,string)` contains the portion of the text that matches the regex

```
$ expect
expect1.1> spawn sh -c {echo '1/ 5  SOMETEXT      Active'}
spawn sh -c echo '1/ 5  SOMETEXT      Active'
4093
expect1.2> expect -re {1/\s+(\d+)\s+SOMETEXT\s+Active}
1/ 5  SOMETEXT      Active
expect1.3> puts $expect_out(1,string)
5
expect1.4> puts $expect_out(0,string)
1/ 5  SOMETEXT      Active
```

Comment: It's usually better to put your regexes in braces to avoid any clashes between characters special to regex and characters special to Tcl.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in this code; there are backslashes in there that need quoting so they go to the RE engine. Try one of these:

```
expect -re "1/\\s+(\\d)\\s+SOMETEXT\\s+Active"
```

```
expect -re {1/\s+(\d)\s+SOMETEXT\s+Active}
```

Note also that `/` is not special at all to Tcl's RE engine *or* to Tcl; it's just an ordinary character. You never need to quote it in itself (unlike with `\` where you need to be careful).